# Transferring files from user's computer to different server without going through GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, file-upload

I'm writing a GAE app in Python that adds user accounts and other services to a third-party data processing service that communicates by SOAP. While using my app, the user sets some parameters, which I want to store in the app's database. The user may also upload large data files, which I don't want to store, since it will drive up usage quotas. Is there a way to transfer files from the user's computer to the third-party service without having the file go through GAE, while still capturing all of the other entered information and initiating the SOAP call?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload form data to a third-party server, but you'll need to use HTML5 APIs that aren't widely available in yet since the standards aren't finalized.

The APIs you'll want to look at are:

- [XHR2](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/XMLHttpRequest-2/), to do the actual upload.  This is an extension of the widely-available XHR API.  You'll probably want the FormData API; for more control, look at the HTTP5 File API (http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/).
- [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), to allow the cross-origin request.  (This is fairly widely supported now, I think.)

Currently, the only browser in wide use which supports all of this is Chrome; FF4 and (I believe) IE9 will as well once they're released.

Short of that, you'll have to proxy requests through your GAE server, which is what you don't want; though you can probably implement it in a way that doesn't keep the data around any longer than needed.